# Why `final var` is illegal in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart2js

The analyzer doesn't say `final var` is illegal.
but dart2js says `final var` is illegal

What is correct? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `var` means mutable variable with explicit `dynamic` type specifier.
The explicit type specifier means that this is not possible specify another type in declaration.

The keyword `final` means `val` or immutable variable with unspecified type, with implicit `dynamic` type.
The implicit type specifier means that this is possible specify other type in declaration.

More precisely variable that declared as `val` are the `value` and `variable` at once.

It are variable because has the `runtime storage`.

But it are also `immutable value` that can be retrieved from associated storage just once and can be used anywhere.

Now consider the following code:

```dart
final var foo;
```

This is the same as the following pseudo code:

```
immutable mutable dynamic foo;
```

Of course, this will not work.

Answer (score 5):

That is probably a bug in the analyzer. `final` and `var` are mutual exclusive.

One of the following is allowed

- final identifier
- final type identifier
- const identifier
- const type identifier
- var identifier
- type identifier

[Dart Programming Language Specification (1.2) - Variables](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.55kzc4r0q21p)

```bnf
finalConstVarOrType:
   final type?
   | const type?
   | varOrType
   ;
varOrType:
   var
   | type
   ;
```

**EDIT**

My DartEditor (Dart VM version: 1.3.0-dev.3.2 (Mon Mar 10 10:15:05 2014) on "linux_x64") shows an error for `final var xxx` (Members can not be declared to be both 'final' and 'var'.)

Comment: yeah thank you for answer this, kind @Günter Zöchbauer :) by the way, I am not able to understand why `var` is not allowed by specification. Perhaps, the type is not fixed at compile time?

Comment: @sunglim `var` specifies that the field allows any type but if the field is `final` it can have only one type - the type of the value it gets initialized with, therefore this two keywords conflict with each other (just my opinion, I have no special insight to the decision make process that took place)

Comment: @sunglim It's much easier. The keyword `var` means mutable variable. The keyword `final` means `val`, immutable variable, or just a value that are not a `const` value but it also are not a mutable. Not a `const` because it has `runtime storage` but at the same time this is just an immutable `value` that stored. Now consider this code: `final var foo` this is the same as `val var foo`. As you can see this is not possible at once declare variable as mutable and immutable.